# Angularjs dropdown date filter

Tags: angularjs

i am not sure if anyone ask this question before. I want to create a date filter like the one google is currently using in their search tools. In this filter, the user can filter a list item by past month, past week, and pass year.

I have an object stored in localStorage

Does any one have any ideas how to do it?. A plunker example would be nice. Thanks

I have an example from codepen

```
`http://codepen.io/PageOnline/pen/nCfAj`
```

Comment: just like any other filter , create a date value  and compare to each item in array. Would help to see what your data looks like

Comment: @charlietfl, so if I have something like that, how would you do that? http://plnkr.co/edit/xScRBzcnt7NBJYOZsJrd?p=preview

Comment: that demo is not a proper working html page and doesn't include any sample data

Comment: @charlietfl here is a working expample http://jsfiddle.net/w7cyhnzf/24/

Comment: a better example is this one http://jsfiddle.net/c6BfQ/3/